# database design of service repair tracking

Tags: database-design

It is both a best practice and optimization question with regards to designing a data model related to servicing machines for existing clients.

The scenario: 
An employee or 2 of them **visit** a **client** to do repair (or other type) services on one or many machines. I also would like to designate the employee who drove the car to the client.
I also would like to capture which employee worked on which machine.
Currently, the company uses one service card to capture repair services of many machines per visit.

I was thinking that each machine must have its own separate service card per visit. That means a visit can include many services, and each service relates to one and only one machine. Each service can be performed by one or many employees. But in order to capture who drove the car to the visit: each visit is made by 1 or many employees.

I am afraid there is a redundancy between visit - employee(s) - service(s) concerning the employee data.

Your suggestions are well appreciated. I am sure there is more then 1 way to doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between recording the data and storing the data.

Having one service card per visit is more efficient from the point of view of the people that have to fill out the service card.

The relational database needs to store that data in a [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) form.

In database terms, the service card can be (should be) highly denormalized.

Here's my attempt at a database schema.

```
Client
------
Client ID
Client Name
...

Employee
--------
Employee ID
Employee Name
...

Machine
-------
Machine ID
Machine Name
...

Service
-------
Service ID
Service Name
...

Client Visit
------------
Client Visit ID
Client ID
Visit Date or Visit Time stamp
...

Client Visit Employee
---------------------
Client Visit Employee ID
Client Visit ID
Employee ID
Driver Boolean

Client Visit Service
--------------------
Client Visit Service ID
Client Visit ID
Employee ID
Machine ID
Service ID
```

Comment: what if I put machine_id as a foreign key in the service table, and remove it from the "Client Visit Service" table?

Comment: The service is a general service, like "Lubricate machine".  You list all of your services once in the Service table.  The Client Visit Service is what ties the general service to a particular machine and a particular client visit.

Comment: so basically you want the technician to select from a list of general services to fulfill the info of Client Visit Service. Right?

Comment: @blaise: The technician can scrawl whatever he wants on the service card.  The application user sitting in front of a GUI selects from a list. Surely, there is a finite list of machine repairs and services.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you might have the following tables

```
Employee
- eid (pk)
- . . .

Machine
- mid (pk)
- . . .

ServiceCall
- sid (pk)
- driver_eid(fk to Employee.eid)
- . . .

ServiceCall_Machine_Employee_Map
- sid (fk to ServiceCall.sid)
- mid (fk to Machine.mid)
- eid (fk to Employee.eid)
- . . .
```

Comment: why do you think it is better to make it many to many, and not a single service card per machine?